# Using a Text Resource with Parameters?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I try to use a formated-string as a resource in Xamarin Studio creating an Android-App

This is part of my Button XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/butAddStation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/butAbout" />
```

And this is the resource:

```
<string name="butAbout">About {0}</string>
<string name="app_name">HVV Forrest</string>
```

I think it is easy to see, what I try to achive. The Button Text should be

```
string.format("About {0}","HVV Forrest");  // About HVV Forrest
```

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this. Can this done completely by markup inside the string resouces or axml-File?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can not be done with XML alone..

XML:

```
<string name="butAbout">About %1$s</string> 
<string name="app_name">HVV Forrest</string>
```

In Code:

```
String.format(getString(R.string.butAbout), getString(R.string.app_name));
```

Comment: Important: Use Java.Lang.String.Format() or it won't work ;)

Comment: @DanielVeihelmann, I know this is very late but I might as well post a solution I found to your problem (for those still searching).  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@DroidBender pointed into the right direction. Still the syntax in Xamarin is a bit different:

```
butAbout.Text = string.Format (GetString(@Resource.String.butAbout),GetString(@Resource.String.app_name);
```

Thanks nontheless, pal

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
dateDisplay.Text = Java.Lang.String.Format (this.GetString(Resource.String.time_selectedDate), date.ToString("d"));

string time = string.Format ("{0}:{1}", hour.ToString(), minute.ToString());
timeDisplay.Text = Java.Lang.String.Format (this.GetString(Resource.String.time_selectedTime), time);
```

For the following string resources:

```
<string name="time_selectedDate" formatted="false">Date %1$s</string>
<string name="time_selectedTime" formatted="false">Time %1$s</string>
```

Comment: Correct, but String.Format does not work correctly unless you specify that it should be used with the Java API in Xamarin. Test it and see. These other answers do not work!

Comment: I don't get why in the first and third lines you use the Java function but in the second one you can use the C# string.Format

Comment: The Xamarin code at the time required this to work properly. You are asking a question about software that is over 4 years old. Xamarin has progressed a lot since it's heyday in '14.

Answer (score 0):

String.Format does not work correctly unless you specify that it should be used with the Java API in Xamarin.  The way to do this is using global::

The following should work, I tested it :)

```
yourTextViewHere.Text = global::Java.Lang.String.Format(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.your_resource_from_string_file), "Your actual string.");
```